# Computer doesn't boot. Shows errors as shown in attached image

Tags: boot, system-installation

Computer at my home hadn't been used/turned on for years. I decided to finally try to turn it on and see if its working. I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a pendrive and booted the computer from pendrive. But the computer started showing error messages as shown in the image below. I am unable to understand from it that what exactly is not working in the computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Other details:

ASUS M2N68-AM SE2 motherboard

AMD Sempron processor

Windows was previously installed on the hard disk but it didn't boot from hard disk. So assuming that hard disk doesn't work, I tried booting from pendrive.

[image: screen as shown during boting]

Comment: Well to some extent you have answered your own question, computer does not boot. You can try google searching those error messages, for example https://serverfault.com/questions/749433/hard-resetting-link-exception-emask-0x50-sact-0x0-serr-0x4090800-action-0xe-froz . Could be a bad drive, could be a bad cable.

Comment: It likely is the drive or the connection to it is broken (you can switching cables and ports to see if it makes a difference). That error message is just from the live installer USB?

Comment: possible the ata controller is bad or connections have degraded from sitting unused. Assuming this is a desktop. I would first reseat all controller cards and cable connections then see if it boots

Comment: Looks like the PC is trying to boot from the hard drive which you say you know doesn't work.  Go into the BIOS and make boot from USB device the first in the boot order.  Note that depending on the age of your hardware you may not be able to boot from USB on your PC.

Comment: I am booting from USB. I will try all the other things - resetting controller card, cables etc. Thanks for help.